# How much amount of money should I show to confirm graduate student visa for Canada?

Tags: canada, student-visa, banking

I have got acceptance for a 2-year research program. Tuition fee is C$12692/year. Living expense is C$6000/year. Supervisor will give me C$5000 for the first year but that depends on my performance in the 1st semester.

But, this variable commitment is not written on my acceptance-letter. Rather that is known through Email.

How much amount should I have to show in my bank to **confirm** my visa on my first try to the embassy?

Would that be enough to show that amount in my father's account?

Comment: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/study/study-how-documents.asp Note that they require C$10000 over the tuition per year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a tuition of $12,692, you would need to show that you have minimum resources of $10,000 in additional funds.

The Government [guide to study in Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/study/study-how-documents.asp) lists what can be used to document your finances.

> **You can prove your funds with:**
>
> - proof of a Canadian bank account in your name, if you have transferred money to Canada
> - Guaranteed Investment Certificate (GIC) from a participating Canadian financial institution
> - proof of a student/education **loan** from a bank
> - your bank statements for the past four months
> - a bank draft that can be converted to Canadian dollars
> - proof you paid tuition and housing fees
> - a letter from the person or school giving you money or
>     proof of funding paid from within Canada, if you have a scholarship or are in a Canadian-funded educational program.
>
> **Minimum funds needed to support yourself as a student**
>   Amount of funds required per year (additional to the tuition): $10,000 ($11,000 for Quebec)
>   Amount of funds required per month (additional to the tuition): $833 ($917 for Quebec)

If the funds are not in an account owned by you, you should provide evidence that they are available to you.